# Heroku performance measure

Tags: java, performance, heroku, server-side

I have Java EE application running on heroku. I need measure load of server CPU. app was runing on my virtual server, I used command `top`. Can I measure load of CPU on heroku server? I need measure server CPU load when I send a lot of requests by `JMeter` from my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for simply installing a Heroku addon designed for application performance monitoring. You can find a list of such addons in the **Analytics** section [here](https://addons.heroku.com/).

I would personally use [New Relic](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) for performance monitoring and resource usage. Just call ***heroku addons:add newrelic*** in your command line and it installs automatically.

Comment: +1, this looks a better and right solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to enable snmp port on heroku server? With that, you can install `mrtg` or other similar tools on your client, and get CPU load, memory usage, network usage and other information.

```
MRTG:  A tool to monitor the traffic load on network-links. Raw data collected via SNMP.
```